# Is it possible to include view to another blade file that requires an ID?

Tags: laravel, routes, laravel-8, laravel-blade, laravel-routing

Ok, Seems it's possible. So here is my explanation.

A controller that requires ID

```
public  function  frameIndex($id){
abort_if(Gate::denies('itinerary_flight_access'), Response::HTTP_FORBIDDEN, '403 Forbidden');

 $iFlights = ItineraryFlight::with(['booking', 'supplier', 'airline'])->where('booking_id', '=',$id)->get();
 return  view('admin.modalCore.frameView.Flight', compact('iFlights'));
}
```

Route

```
Route::get('iflight/view/{id}', 'IFlightController@frameIndex');
```

Then I tried to include this view into another view file as following

```
@include('admin.modalCore.frameView.i-flight', [$bookingCore->id])
```

But it's not working. Any solutions for this situation?

Comment: The view itself doesn't require the id, the route is what requires the id. The route seems to require `iFlights` and you can inlclude it with those via `@include('admin.modalCore.frameView.i-flight', [ 'iFlights' => <variable containing iflights> ])` however it's best practice to get that variable in the controller that produces this view

Answer (score 0):

You pass the parameter like this

```
@include('admin.modalCore.frameView.i-flight', ['id' => $bookingCore->id])
```

Comment: shouldnt be $BookingCore but $iFlights

Comment: im not 100% sure what he needs to pass, but generally that is how you pass any type of variable

Comment: yep syntax is okay. I suppose he must pass whatever he compacted from the controller

Answer (score 0):

```
@include('admin.modalCore.frameView.i-flight', ['iFlights' => App\Models\ItineraryFlight::with(['booking', 'supplier', 'airline'])->where('booking_id', $bookingCore->id)->get()])
```